# Prove $|\max\{x, y\} - z| \leq |x - z|$ for $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y \leq z$?

Tags: inequality

I am trying to check if the following 2 elementary inequality claims  are true.

**Claim 1:**

Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $y \leq z$.

Then the following inequality holds $$|\max\{x, y\} - z| \leq |x - z|$$

To check this I believe we can proceed as follows:

\begin{align}
    |\max\{x, y\} - z|
    & \leq |\max\{x, z\} - z| \tag{since $y \leq z$} \\
    & \leq |x - z|
\end{align}

Where the last line follows since if $x = z$, then $|\max\{x, z\} - z| = |z - z| = 0$. Otherwise if $x \neq z$, then $|x - z| > 0$, so it is always bigger than $|\max\{x, z\} - z|$.

**Claim 2:**

Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $y \leq z$.

Then the following inequality holds $$|\max\{x, y\} - z| \leq |x - z|$$

I believe that Claim 2 follows from Claim 1, by applying the increasing function $x \mapsto x^{2}$ on $x \geq 0$ to both sides of our Claim 1 result (assuming it is true). Is this logic to prove the Claim 2 result **assuming** Claim 1 is true, correct? I believe this is true since both Claim 1 and Claim 2 use the same underlying assumptions on $x, y, z$.

**Update:** Made it clear that the conditions for Claim 1 and Claim 2 are the same, i.e., they are for $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y \leq z$.

**Update 2:** I've edited Claim 1 and Claim 2, since I believe I may have caused confusion, given the thoughtful response from @RWPardo.

I'm not sure the above reasoning is correct, or if the inequality is true. I may have missed something. Could anyone please confirm, and then show it more rigorously than I have? If there is a counterexample, how could this type of inequality be made true?

Comment: If $x\geq y$, then $$\vert \max\{ x,y\} -z\vert =\vert x-z\vert.$$ Thus, we only need to consider the case $x<y\leq z$. Then we have $$\vert \max\{ x,y\} -z\vert =\vert y-z\vert =z-y \leq z-x=\vert x-z\vert.$$

Comment: Your proof does not work, consider $x=0=y, z=1$, then you would need $1\leq 0$ in your second step.

Comment: @Severin Schraven Thanks! Appreciate your help. A couple of follow ups. To confirm, the result as stated is true, but my proof is incorrect (which you have corrected)? And is the second claim then correct $(\max\{x, y\} - z)^{2} \leq (x - z)^{2}$, for the reason I stated above?

Comment: Noe that your first line after " I believe we can proceed as follows" is incorrect. EG take $y = 1, x = 2, z = 3$, then you're saying that $ | 2 - 3 | \leq |3 - 3 |$.

Comment: Thanks kindly @CalvinLin, appreciate the teaching. Per my replies above to Severin Schraven, do you agree with them so that I can close this?

Comment: 1) The result is true 2) Your proof is still incorrect (EG I pointed out that the start is false). 3) I'm not sure what the "second claim" is since it's not labelled, but given that the start is false, I'd encourage you to rework it completely.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinLin, sorry I meant my two follow up questions in my replies above. You have confirmed that the result is true and my proof is incorrect. I believe Severin's suggested reply proof is correct, yes? And also is the follow up claim that $(\max\{x, y\} - z)^{2} \leq (x - z)^{2}$ then true for the reasoning I gave in my original post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**First and easy proof of your question**:

---

If $\max\{x,y\} = x$, we have nothing to do, since the inequality holds.  On the other hand, if $\max\{x,y\} = y$, we have $y \geq x.$ This implies that $$-y\leq -x \tag{*}.$$ On the other hand, since $y \leq z,$ we have $z-y=|y-z| = |\max\{x,y\} - z|.$ Hence, $$z-y=|y-z| = |\max\{x,y\} - z|\overset{(*)}{\leq} z - x \leq |x-z|, $$ which ends the proof.

---

**On your second clain**:

*Your second claim is partially right!*

Let $a \geq b \geq 0$, we also have that there exist a $t\geq 0$ such that $a =  b +t$, hence $a^2 =  b^2 +2 t b +t^2. $ Since $s= 2 t b +t^2 \geq 0$, we have that $$a^2 \geq b^2.$$ Hence the function $f: [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x^{2}$ is an increasing function.

*Why partially right?*

Only using that the function $f$ is increasing is not enough. That's because the inequality $|\max\{x,y\} - z| \leq |z-x|$ does not hold for general $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R},$ but only for $y\leq z.$ The good thing is that proving that $|\max\{x,y\} - z| \leq |z-x|$ for $y\leq z$ is equivalent to proving $(\max\{x,y\} - z)^2 \leq (z-x)^2$ for $y\leq z$. The bad thing is that proving the squared inequality is harder than proving the actually wanted inequality. As a way of saying sorry of my previous and first answer (the second edited answer), I will convince you that proving the squared inequality is harder.

---

**Second and “hard” proof of your question using the squared inequality**:

---

*Proving the squared inequality*:

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ be real numbers, calling $\max \{x,y\} = w$, we have,
\begin{align*}
(w - z)^2 \leq (x-z)^2 \iff &  w^2 - 2 w z + z^2 \leq x^2-2 x z +z^2 \\
\iff &  w^2 - 2 w z + z^2 \leq x^2-2 x z +z^2 \\
\iff &  w^2 - 2 w z \leq x^2-2 x z  \\
\iff &  w^2 - x^2 \leq 2 w z - 2 x z \\
\iff &  (w-x)(w+x) \leq 2z ( w -x ) \tag{**} \\
\end{align*} The only thing that is left to us is to prove that $(w-x)(w+x) \leq 2z ( w -x )$ for all $z \geq y.$ If $w=x$, nothing we have to prove, since $ 0 = (w-x)(w+x) \leq 2z ( w -x ) = 0.$ On the other hand, if $w>x,$ we have $$w = y \tag{***}$$ and $$y>x \tag{****}$$ since $w=\max\{x,y\}$. Now, note that
\begin{align}
w + x \overset{(***)}{=} & y + x \\
\overset{(****)}{<} & y + y \\ 
\overset{y \leq z }{\leq} & 2 z \tag{*****}.
\end{align} Hence, since $w - x>0$, we have $(w + x) (w - x) \leq 2z (w - x), $ which proves $(**)$ and, hence, your desired inequality. It were harder, right?

---

**Answering questions in the comments**:

---

Before answering here, keep calm. I'm not aware of all your background, but I can clarify some things first. It's not a 7-headed boss in a hard game.

**1**)  *Is everything in my first claim right?*

Unfortunately, no. In the passage $$|\max\{x, y\} - z| \leq |\max\{x, z\} - z| \tag{since $y \leq z$},$$ you seem to need to use that the modulus function increases, but it does not. For example, take $x=1$, $y=2$, and $z=3$, we have that $z\geq y$, but it does not hold that $$|\max\{x, y\} - z| \leq |\max\{x, z\} - z|,$$ since the right side is zero and the left side, in modulus, equal to 1.

**2**) *If the first claim was true, my second claim would be true?*

Yes, I agree with this, but it is not true, as said in **1**.

**3**) *You said*:

> *And is my understanding correct that you have proved a much stronger clai, i.e., $(\max\{x,y\}−z)^2 \leq (x−z)^2, \forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$, with no restriction that $y \leq z$?*

No, I have used that $y \leq z$ in the inquality $(*****).$

**4**) *You said:*

> *Also the second inequality does quickly follow from the first. I'm convinced now since $x \mapsto x^2$ is an increasing map for each $x \geq 0$. Since our first inequality is for non-negative terms (assuming x,y,z such that $y\leq z$), we can square both sides and conclude. @fleablood confirmed this reasoning is correct below. I'm still not sure of the reasoning behind your more complicated proof*.

I can't say what @fleablood confirmed. I can confirm that the function $x \mapsto x^2$ restricted to $[0,\infty)$ is an increasing function. On the other hand, as I have said before, only using this is not enough for proving your result. You will need to use that $y \leq z$ and **first claim** is wrong, as I said before.

**5**) *Why the second proof is harder?*

This is because we can't assume the $$|\max\{x,y\} - z| \leq |x-z|,$$ for $y\leq z,$ since this is the desired result. Assuming the conclusion to prove itself is called a [Circular reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning). So, if we want to prove the desired inequality, and we can't use the conclusion, we would need to work out the things first. That's what I did.

Comment: Thanks! very nicely presented for my learning. And is my second claim correct in my original post?

Comment: Yeah, It's right! I have made an edit to complete the proof of your statement.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your kind help and follow up.

Comment: I have made another huge edit saying sorry for an incorrect answer. If you want to follow what was wrong, you can read my edit again.

Comment: Thanks. Though, my second claim was following from my conditions from the first claim, i.e., $\forall x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $y \leq z$. I think perhaps this was unclear, but I tried to clarify it in my replies above. Under these conditions using the proof of the first claim, and the fact that $x \mapsto x^{2}$, I simply wanted to check that concluding claim 2 was correct.

Comment: Do you agree with this? And is my understanding correct that you have proved a _much_ stronger claim, i.e., $(\max \{x, y\}-z)^{2} \leq(x-z)^{2}$, for all $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$, with **no** restriction that $y \leq z$?

Comment: Also the second inequality does quickly follow from the first. I'm convinced now since $x \mapsto x^{2}$ is an increasing map for each $x \geq 0$. Since our first inequality is for non-negative terms (assuming $x, y, z$ such that $y \leq z$), we can square both sides and conclude. @fleablood confirmed this reasoning is correct below. I'm still not sure of the reasoning behind your more complicated proof.

Comment: I think I answered your questions again in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133437/discussion-between-user4687531-and-r-w-prado).

Answer (score 1):

Your first line doesn't work

If $y \le z$ then $\max(x,y) \le z$ and $\max(x,y) - z \le \max(x,z) - z$ but that does not mean that $|\max(x,y) - z| \le |\max(x,z)-z|$

Counter example:  $x=1$ and $y= 2$ and $z=57493085940386403869043$.  Then $\max(x,y) - z = 2 - 57493085940386403869043 = -57493085940386403869041 < 0 = \max(x,z) -z$ but $|\max(x,y)-z| = +57493085940386403869041 > 0 =|\max(x,z)- z|$.

....

I'd consider the two cases $\max{x,y} < z$ and $z \le \max{x,y}$.

If $\max {x,y} < z$ then $x < z$ and so we have $|\max(x,y)-z| = z-\max(x,y)$ and $|x-z| = z-x$.  Ans as $\max(x,y) \ge x$ then $z-\max(x,y) \le z - x$.

And if $z \ge \max{x,y}$ then $|\max(x,y)-z| = \max(x,y) -z$ and $|x-z|$ ... well, we don't know how $x$ compares with $z$ so we can consider cases $x < y$ then $\max(x,y) = y \le z$ so $x < z$ so $|x-z|=x-z$ ans we have $\max(x,y)-z \ge x-z$.

And if $z\ge \max{x,y}$ and $x\ge y$ then $\max(x,y)=x$ and $|\max(x,y)-z| = |x-z|$.

....

As for the second claim:

Yes... if $a< b \implies f(a) < f(b)$ then as we have shown $|\max(x,y)-z| \le |x-z|$ we can conclude $f(|\max(x,y)-z|) \le f(|\max(x,y)-z)$.

But *is* $x \mapsto x^2$ an increasing function?  Note: $-3 < 2$ but $(-3)^2 = 9 > 4 = 2^2$.  On which conditions is $x\mapsto x^2$ increasing? You need to take care of that.

(Also, maybe you need to confirm that $|M|^2 = M^2$ but... I'll grant you that one.)

Comment: Thanks! For the second claim, I mentioned that $x \mapsto x^{2}$ for $x \geq$ 0, since this is where this map is increasing. So this allows the second claim to be concluded, correct?

Comment: Yes.... assuming we can assume $x\mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$ which... presumably you can assume that.

Comment: I'd also note that when I said "I'd consider the two cases maxx,y<z and z≤maxx,y" that even though *I* would do that it wouldn't necessarily mean I made the easiest choice.  As R.W. Padro did in their answer I could also have considered the two cases $x\le y$ and $y\le x$ and as it turns out that'd *quite* a bit simpler in the end.